# Can I make each column value for a specific index its own row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example DF:

```
    0   1   2
0   A   1   2
1   B   3   1
```

Can I turn the example DF into this:

```
    0   1   
0   A   1   
1   A   2
2   B   3   
3   B   1
```

Comment: have you looked at `df.melt`?

Comment: Let me take a look into it.

Comment: Use: `df.melt('0', value_name='1').drop('variable', 1)`

Comment: Heck @Mayank, smart. I didn't expect `melt` to be able to handle just a normal column...I thought it only worked for column names. Guess I have some learning to do... :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt`:

```
new_df = df.melt('0').set_index('0')['value'].sort_index().reset_index().set_axis([0, 1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   0  1
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  3
3  B  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'A': [1,2], 'B':[3,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  1

pd.melt(frame=df)

  variable  value
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        B      3
3        B      1
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: There is not much to explain here... it's just what melt does. One can read the docs if it is curious :)